# Django URL Design

Tags: django, django-urls

I often find myself falling into a world in which I am not so sure about the URLs that I came up with. I think that's mainly because I have a few questions regarding URL design in django that remain unanswered.

Say, I have built a public profile page for my site users. It can be accessed by providing an user id. Should the user id be part of the URL (ie. `/profile/<userid>/`) or should it be provided in the querystring (`/profile?userid=<userid>`)? And why?

I use AJAX extensively in my project. Should the AJAX URLs be designed differently from their counterparts? Is there a design pattern for this purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't any hard-and-fast rule here. I'd say that anything which is reasonably static should use the `/profile/<userid>/` format. GET parameters - `?userid=<userid>` - should be reserved for things that are more dynamic, are just difficult to encode as part of the URL (such as a set of search terms), or when you need several parameters at once and can't count on the order.

Comment: Does that also mean that a view with optional parameters like several criteria for a search should be passed in as GET parameters? Could one also argument with a more REST-like approach that each resource should be represented by an URL or is that not a valid consideration in this case?

Answer (score 3):

Django discourages the use of query strings and encourages the use of pretty URLs. You just have to set them up properly in your `URLconf`. If you haven't read the [Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/) (available freely online), you should. It talks about this in [chapter 3](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter03/):

> **A Word About Pretty URLs**
>
> If you’re experienced in another Web
>   development platform, such as PHP or Java, you may be thinking, “Hey,
>   let’s use a query string parameter!” — something like
>   `/time/plus?hours=3`, in which the hours would be designated by the
>   hours parameter in the URL’s query string (the part after the ?).
>
> You can do that with Django (and we’ll tell you how in Chapter 7), but
>   one of Django’s core philosophies is that URLs should be beautiful.
>   The URL `/time/plus/3/` is far cleaner, simpler, more readable, easier
>   to recite to somebody aloud and … just plain prettier than its query
>   string counterpart. Pretty URLs are a characteristic of a quality Web
>   application.
>
> Django’s URLconf system encourages pretty URLs by making it easier to
>   use pretty URLs than not to.

This chapter details how and why to do this!

Comment: In the Django Book, I picked up the following comment from Tobu.

"Pretty urls have one disadvantage: they come unquoted (see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3875#section-4.1.5 ), and unquoting can lose information compared to percent-encoding. For example, C%2B%2B+Java will become C+++Java in the url and in captures."

Comment: Another good point from the Django Book and mentioned by BDP.

"It might be useful to note that a pretty URL also "looks" good to many search engine indexers so having pretty URLs has a search engine optimization advantage too."

Comment: To the unquoting, if you use proper unquoting, that is not the case. Example: `import urllib; print urllib.unquote_plus("C%2B%2B+Java")` returns `'C++ Java'`. Know your libraries! :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same doubt some time ago, and the project leader of my company said me:

"**Try to avoid infinite amount of differents URLs**"

So, if some parameter can generate infinite differents URLs, it should be send as a parameter (like this: .com?param=), for example a timestamp. There is infinite amount of differents timestamps, so it should be a paramenter.

In the other hand there are values that are bounded, for example one object ID. If you put and ID in the URL, in the worst case you can generate the same amounts of URLs than IDs, but not infinite URLs. In this case the ID can be included in the URL (like this: .com/content//view)

This simple phrase helped me a lot, I hope you too =)